# How to allow my user to have custom domain?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I would like to create a feature that allow my users to have custom domain. Like what blogger/wordpress is doing.

e.g.

```
http://www.domain.com
```

User can have own custom domain

```
http://www.custom.com
```

In which typing in www.custom.com maps to www.domain.com

How do i do so? I am using php. Is this a server configuration?

Comment: Yes, what HTTP server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have to change the DNS of the new site to forward to their site.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast reply. what do you mean by dns? what is the configuration. any tips on giving me the right direction to research appreciated greatly! do i need to do anything on my application or its a configuration thingy?

Comment: I am trying to create a feature like https://support.zendesk.com/entries/13976-mapping-a-host-name-of-your-own-to-zendesk-using-cname

Answer (score 1):

I do this with my multi-account platform. I use the cpanel api to create an add-on domain each time they specify their domain name and I ask them to change the name-servers on their domain to my hosting. 
So here's an example:
www.example.com
ask user to change nameservers to ns1.hostingwerks.com and ns2.hostingwerks.com
prompt user for their domain
use api to add on their domain
tell user it's done but allow some time for it to propigate
This requires you to have whm access, but it might give you some help.

```
if(!empty($domain) AND $olddomain != $domain){

    $d = explode(".",$origdomain);
    if(count($d) != 1){
    if($d[0] == "www" OR $d[0] == "http://www" OR $d[0] == "https://www"){
    $origdomain = $d[1] .".". $d[2];
    }
    else {
    $origdomain = $d[0] .".". $d[1];
    }
    }
    if(substr($origdomain, 0, 8) == "https://"){
    $origdomain = substr($origdomain, 8);
    }
    elseif(substr($origdomain, 0, 7) == "http://"){
    $origdomain = substr($origdomain, 7);
    }
    $dom = $origdomain;
    $user = "your cpanel client username";
    $addonpass = "your new domain's password";
    $cpanel_skin = "x3";
    $passw = "your cpanel password";
    $ownername = "your cpanel hosting user name";
    $pass = "your cpanel password";
    $host = "localhost";
    //Using 'explode' breaks the domain into its constituent pieces, the name and the extension (TLD), and puts them in an array
    $domai = explode('.',$dom);
    /*the directory path is defined by the first element appended to public_html.  It does not matter where this file, 'addonhelper.php', is located - 
    the program will always install the addon domains to this directory.  If this needs to be changed, this line needs to be updated.
    Some versions of Cpanel do not allow for this to be changed and will ignore changes.  Most notably - version X.*/
    $dir="public_html/sys";
    //the user is the first element of the $domain, as requested
    $user=trim($domai[0]);
    //put the domain back together and trim whitespace.
    $dom=trim($domai[0]).".".trim($domai[1]);
    //create the cpanel request.
    $request = "/frontend/$cpanel_skin/addon/doadddomain.html?domain=$dom&user=$user&dir=$dir&pass=$addonpass";
    //process the request with addondomain below
    $sock = @fsockopen($host,2082);
    if(!$sock) {
        print('Socket error');
        exit();
    }
    //authenticate the connection
    $authstr = "$ownername:$passw";
    //make the passphrase slightly more difficult to decipher
    $pass = base64_encode($authstr);
    $in = "GET $request\r\n";
    $in .= "HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $in .= "Host:$host\r\n";
    $in .= "Authorization: Basic $pass\r\n";
    $in .= "\r\n";
    //process
    fputs($sock, $in);
    while (!feof($sock)) {
        $result .= fgets ($sock,128);
    }
    fclose( $sock );
```

Comment: any idea how they did it @ https://support.zendesk.com/entries/13976-mapping-a-host-name-of-your-own-to-zendesk-using-cname?

I realized that user need to input their custom domain(in the app) after pointing the cname. What do we do with the custom domain collected? -> this is the part i am confused.

Comment: Add their domain to your hosting as an add-on with the folder set to the same as your main domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to change a single domain, change the nameservers on it to the same, and set it up as an add on in your plesk/cpanel to the same folder. Or you can forward the domain and mask it. That works too. http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/422/forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name